# Extremals of a Functional with two functions

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Find the extremals of the functional
$$J[y, z] = \int_0^\frac{π}{2} ((y')^2 + (z')^2 + 2yz) \,dx$$

subject to the boundary conditions $y(0) = 0, y(\frac{π}{2})= 1, z(0) = 0, z(\frac{π}{2}) = 1$

Do I need to convert y and z to polar coordinates so they have the same variables? I do not have any examples like this in my textbook or notes.

Comment: what do you get after applying [Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations)?

Answer (score 1):

Extremals should be found among the solutions of the Euler–Lagrange equations:
$$
  \left\{
   \begin{array}{l}
     F'_y-\frac{d}{dx}F'_{y'}=0,\\
     F'_z-\frac{d}{dx}F'_{z'}=0
   \end{array}
  \right.  
  \Leftrightarrow
  \left\{
   \begin{array}{l}
     2z-2y''=0,\\
     2y-2z''=0.
   \end{array}
  \right.  
$$
Here $F$ is the function under the integral. From that system one can find $y,z$ (there will be some constants involved). Those constants can be found using the boundary conditions.